# What does it mean to have teeth in the English style?

Tags: meaning, french-language, guy-de-maupassant, bel-ami

In Chapter VI of Maupassant's novel *Bel-Ami*, the journalist Robert de Varenne describes the Baroness de Livar as follows (emphasis added):

> Une grande sèche, soixante ans, frisons faux, **dents à l'anglaise**, esprit de Restauration, toilettes même époque.

English translation:

> A tall dried-up woman, sixty years old, false curls, **English-style teeth**, ideas from the [Restoration Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourbon_Restoration), style of dressing from the same period.

What is meant by "dents à l'anglaise"? (And is my translation even correct?)

Comment: They may be referring to [the myth of bad English teeth](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-32883893), although that seems a bit too current a stereotype.

Comment: And... apparently I'm wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Google search for the term reveals that [it means the same thing as "buck teeth"](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=bucktooth), large front teeth.

> In French, buck teeth are called *dents à l'anglaise*, literally "English teeth."

Also [here](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/17822):

> ***dents à l'anglaise***  *Dents longues et proéminentes*

[It's apparently not in current usage](https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/1hz3r0/til_in_french_buck_teeth_are_called_dents_%C3%A0/cazldjs/).

Comment: No dice in Google NGrams, but I'm not getting many hits for french terms there in general.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find it in *Le Petit Robert* (which is not really *petit*), even though it has other expressions using the phrase "à l'anglaise".